# Div does not totally expanding 100% height

Tags: css, html

I'd like to expand the left div to the bottom of the page. But the problem is that it stops on the bottom of the page but when I scroll down, it stays at its vertical size! It doesn't expand with scroll dow :-( Any idea please?

The html:

```
<div class="menu_gauche">

<div class="ligne_menu_gauche"><div class="accueil"></div><div class="menu_txt">Accueil<a href="/bgladm"><span class="fullspan"></span></a></div></div>
<div class="ligne_menu_gauche" style="background:#FAFAFA;"><div class="compte"></div><div class="menu_txt">Compte<a href="/bgladm-compte"><span class="fullspan"></span></a></div></div>
<div class="ligne_menu_gauche"><div class="options"></div><div class="menu_txt">Options<a href="/bgladm-options"><span class="fullspan"></span></a></div></div>
<div class="ligne_menu_gauche"><div class="notif"></div><div class="menu_txt">Notifications<a href="/bgladm-notif"><span class="fullspan"></span></a></div></div>
<div class="ligne_menu_gauche"><div class="aide"></div><div class="menu_txt">Aide<a href=""><span class="fullspan"></span></a></div></div>
<div class="ligne_menu_gauche"><div class="logout"></div><div class="menu_txt">Deconnexion<a href="/logout"><span class="fullspan"></span></a></div></div>

<div class="vide_menu_gauche"></div>
</div>

<div class="contenu_droit"><div class="envglob_form">
<div class="enveloppe_form">
<input type="text" class="input_text_compte" value="" id="email_compte"> <span>Email</span><br>l
</div>

<div class="enveloppe_form">
<input type="password" class="input_text_compte" id="mdp_actuel"> <span>Mot de passe actuel</span><br><br>
<input type="password" class="input_text_compte" id="mdp_1"> <span>Nouveau mot de passe</span><br>
<input type="password" class="input_text_compte" id="mdp_2"> <span>Retappez le mot de passe</span>
</div>

<div class="enveloppe_form">
<input type="text" class="input_text_compte" id="nom_compte" value=""> <span>Nom</span><br>
<input type="text" class="input_text_compte" id="prenom_compte" value=""> <span>Prénom</span><br>
</div>

<div class="enveloppe_form">
<input type="radio" name="sexe_compte" id="sexe_compteh" value="1"> Homme<br>
<input type="radio" name="sexe_compte" id="sexe_comptef" value="0" checked=""> Femme
</div>

<div class="enveloppe_form"><select id="age"><option value="1933">1933</option><option value="1934">1934</option><option value="1935">1935</option><option value="2004">2004</option></select> <span>Année de naissance</span>
</div>

</div>

<div class="envglob_form2">
<div class="enveloppe_form">
<div class="interets"><span>Centres d'intérêt</span></div><div class="interets" id="interets_id"><div class="interet_compte"><input type="checkbox" name="interets[]" value="1"> Actualités</div><div class="interet_compte"><input type="checkbox" name="interets[]" value="2" checked=""> Animaux</div><div class="interet_compte"><input type="checkbox" name="interets[]" value="3"> Art</div><div class="interet_compte"><input type="checkbox" name="interets[]" value="4" checked=""> Automobile</div><div class="interet_compte"><input type="checkbox" name="interets[]" value="27"> Autre</div><div class="interet_compte"><input type="checkbox" name="interets[]" value="5"> Cinéma</div><div class="interet_compte"><input type="checkbox" name="interets[]" value="6"> Famille</div><div class="interet_compte"><input type="checkbox" name="interets[]" value="7"> Finance</div><div class="interet_compte"><input type="checkbox" name="interets[]" value="8"> Formation</div><div class="interet_compte"><input type="checkbox" name="interets[]" value="9"> Gastronomie</div><div class="interet_compte"><input type="checkbox" name="interets[]" value="10"> Humour</div><div class="interet_compte"><input type="checkbox" name="interets[]" value="11"> Immobilier</div><div class="interet_compte"><input type="checkbox" name="interets[]" value="12"> Informatique</div><div class="interet_compte"><input type="checkbox" name="interets[]" value="13" checked=""> Internet</div><div class="interet_compte"><input type="checkbox" name="interets[]" value="14"> Jeux</div><div class="interet_compte"><input type="checkbox" name="interets[]" value="15"> Littérature</div><div class="interet_compte"><input type="checkbox" name="interets[]" value="16" checked=""> Maison</div><div class="interet_compte"><input type="checkbox" name="interets[]" value="17"> Mode</div><div class="interet_compte"><input type="checkbox" name="interets[]" value="18"> Moto</div><div class="interet_compte"><input type="checkbox" name="interets[]" value="19"> Musique</div><div class="interet_compte"><input type="checkbox" name="interets[]" value="20"> People</div><div class="interet_compte"><input type="checkbox" name="interets[]" value="21"> Photographie</div><div class="interet_compte"><input type="checkbox" name="interets[]" value="22"> Santé</div><div class="interet_compte"><input type="checkbox" name="interets[]" value="23" checked=""> Sciences</div><div class="interet_compte"><input type="checkbox" name="interets[]" value="24"> Sport</div><div class="interet_compte"><input type="checkbox" name="interets[]" value="25"> Téléphonie</div><div class="interet_compte"><input type="checkbox" name="interets[]" value="26"> Voyage</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="env_save">
<div id="canvasloader-container" class="loading_anim" style="display: none;"><div id="canvasLoader" style="display: block; position: absolute; top: -49px; left: -49px;"><canvas width="98" height="98"></canvas><canvas width="98" height="98" style="display: none;"></canvas></div></div>
<div class="save" id="save_compte"></div>
</div>
<a href="/supprcompte" class="bouton_suppr">Supprimer le compte</a>
</div>
```

And you'll find the css on the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/gMNzd/

Comment: your code is not valid. plese check your opening and closing div-tags

Comment: I took a look at it and this may not answer your question but I would use position fixed instead of worrying about it scrolling.

Comment: i think you're lacking for a clear. please check this

Comment: Michael: yes, you're right, I've modified, but not changement : http://jsfiddle.net/gMNzd/3/

Comment: Evan: you're right! I've done it and it's better... :-)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've managed to solve this problem in the past is with a little bit of JS *used jQuery for the simplified syntax, but pure JS will work just as well):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menu_gauche").height($(".contenu_droit").height());
});
```

Additionally, you'll have to also add some top/bottom padding to the `.menu_gauche` to match `.contenu_droit` for a more perfect alignment.

```
.menu_gauche{
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gMNzd/4/

Comment: Thanks Nicolae, finally, I've chossen the evan solution: change div to fixed!

Answer (score 0):

if you want the height to adjust accordingly you can add a clearfix

```
<div class="left-div">your content here<div class="clearfix"></div></div>
```

clearfix explain here...check the link
http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html

Comment: I believe there is a different issue described in the question. Consider making the yellow box from the demo the same height with the green one.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna take a look at http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-2-column-left-menu-pixels.htm

It's describes the solution to your problem.

Another possible solution (more easy to my opinion) is using *display: table*, *display: table-row* and *display: table-cell*. Since you are actually using columns, the table-behaviour might be just what you are looking for. This is likely not to work in older browsers though, so it kinda depends on what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Change the .menu_gauche to fixed and give the .contenu_droit margin-left. 
Please check this Fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/gMNzd/5/

```
.menu_gauche{
    position:fixed; /* Change the Position to fixed */
    top:0 ; /* Added */
    left: 0; /* Added */
    bottom: 0; /* Added */
 .contenu_droit {
    margin-left: 175px;
}
```

It would also better considering usability as you will always have access to the navigation.